# Is it possible to center a image and resize the image according with the screen resolution?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a square image (for instagram) - 1080x1080 pixels.

I need to center the image and resize the image according with the resolution. If resolution is 1920x1080 - then I have a image with 1080x1080.

If the resolution is 1280x720 - I will have 720x720.

I tried:

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Works fine to center the image - but the image doesn't resize correctly.

Comment: How about `width: 100vh`

Comment: If you use an background image you could set `background-size: contain;` (as big as possible, no cutting, keeping aspect ratio) example: https://jsfiddle.net/2vq5extx/

Comment: hi @Santi ! your solution fits perfectly! but I have a issue now.. On desktop ok Screens are WIDE - then the width is the large side. but When I try your solution on tablets or cellphones, with the height large than width - works but the image is cutted on the right side. tks!!

Comment: So essentially, you need the image to be the biggest, fully-visible square possible at any given resolution? I think VXp's solution below, as well as @RolandStarke's above, satisfy that requirement. Mine was based on the assumption that you were always looking to reduce the width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this (bare minimum):

```css
html, body {margin: 0; height: 100%}

img {
  display: block; /* removes bottom margin/whitespace */
  margin: 0 auto; /* you probably only want to center it horizontally */
  max-width: 100%; /* horizontally responsive */
  max-height: 100%; /* vertically responsive */
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1080" alt="img">
```

Answer (score 1):

If the height should always be the same as the full screen height, you can use `height: 100%` and `width: auto`, together with `margin: 0 auto` which will center it horizontally.